# Redirect to action from async action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, redirecttoaction

I have following code

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> login(string login, string password)
        {
            User objUser = new User();
            string result = await HomeAPI.getlogin(login, password);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                try
                {
                    objUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(result);
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(objUser.api_key, null))
                    {
                        return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() =>
                        {
                            if (true)
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

and project controller like thsi

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return  View();
        }
```

Its hitting the action of project controller but redirection is not working, means still on login page

I also tried per suggestion

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
           ActionResult x = await Index();
            return  View();
        }
```

It throws overflow exception.

I am stuck please how to redirect to project controller view.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no exception being thrown inside that try/catch? And that the api_key is not null? try to run it in debug and see. Add some tracing to see in your log file what is going on. An never let a empty catch, because you won't be aware of the exception.

Comment: I have debug the code and sure no exception is there, its hitting project controller but view not rendering, stuck on login view only

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");` does it stop ?

Comment: yes it hit the breakpoint

Comment: Is it a regular HTTP call or an AJAX call? What response is the server giving to the browser? Can you see the server sending an HTTP 302 ? Use Chrome inspector : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance

Comment: in network it is showing status 200 and type = xhr